# How to force user to turn on gps to use app in ionic2

Tags: cordova, gps, ionic2

I want to force users to turn on GPS in ionic2 app for this I am using dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy

I have installed this plugin but why it is saying plugin not installed.

this my function what I am trying to do if app loads this onLocate function will trigger and check whether GPS is on or Not if not on this will prompt to turn on GPS see this image

but if the user tapped on cancel button I want to re-run this function and prompt again to ask the user to turn on GPS as shown in above image until user tap on ok to start GPS then I want to reload window to get user location using GPS.

where I am wrong

```
onLoacte(){

 this.locationAccuracy.canRequest().then((canRequest: boolean) => {

      if(canRequest) {
        // the accuracy option will be ignored by iOS
          this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
          () => console.log('Request successful'),
          error =>  location.reload(),
        );
      }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call that function in a loop may be, till you get the `locationAccuracy.request` successfully.

Also give the users a `button` to stop looking for location or exit the app in doing so.

Comment: Hi pro_cheats. Can show the code for looping plz thanks

Comment: See this for `do{ something } while (success);` loops in javascript -https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_dowhile.asp